# If water is a bad conductor of heat (C=4200J per kg per K), why is it used as coolant/water cooling? :O

Tags: thermodynamics, water, conductors

According to what I’m seeing, water is considered a bad conductor of heat.

Colloquially, isn’t water supposed to conduct heat well as it’s used to transfer heat to a radiator, in everything form a pc to a nuclear reactor? :3

Comment: Thermal conductivity and specific heat are two different things.

Answer (score 5):

First, what you referred to in the title is the heat capacity, not the heat conductivity.

Second, if you can enforce a high substance flow, you do not need to have high conductivity, but rather only high heat capacity. High heat conductivity is only important if you can't move the medium (like solid metal taking up and carrying away the heat).

Third, it is used as a coolant because its heat capacity is way larger than that of air. To the very least this is due to its density being a factor of 1000 higher. But even if you compare it per mass, the heat capacity is still higher than that of air, because of the higher number of degrees of freedom of the water molecule compared to air molecules (taking up more kinetic energy), and I guess also due to hydrogen bonds (taking up more potential energy than the van-der-Waals interaction between air molecules).

Fourth, it is preferred over other possible liquid substances (like mercury) because it is non-toxic or otherwise dangerous. Plus it is extraordinarily cheap. You just have to open your tap and let it run. BTW there are also nuclear reactors that are cooled with liquid sodium (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sodium-cooled_fast_reactor), something you would not want to have in your PC unless you feel like Chuck Norris on crack.

Comment: Even taking the density into account, the heat capacity per unit mass of water (i.e., the specific heat) is still about four times larger than that of air.  So it's a more effective coolant for multiple reasons.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert: thanks for the comment. I updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

When water is being used as a coolant, it is common to actively stir it or pump it fast enough through the cooling pipes to yield good mixing. This makes up for its poor conductivity and thus lets us exploit its high heat capacity.